# Cauchy estimates type inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ an open set and $K$ a compact of $\Omega$.

If $V\subset \Omega$ is a compact neighborhood of $K$ then there exist constants $C_1,\cdots,C_n$ such that for all holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ and for all $n$ we have $$\sup_K\vert f^{(n)}(z)\vert\le C_n\sup_V\vert f\vert.$$

It looks like Cauchy estimates but not sure what is the definition of *compact neighborhood of $K$* if it is for all $z\in K$ there exist $r>0$ such that $D(z,r)\subset V$ we can always reduce $r$ to have $\overline{D(z,r)}\subset V.$

So that now I can apply Cauchy estimates which gives me $\sup_K \vert f^{(n)}(z)\vert\le C_n\sup_V\vert f\vert.$

But I assume there is a gap in "my" proof because I didn't really use the fact that $K$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V$ a compact neighborhood of $K$ means $V$ is compact and $K$ is contained in the interior of $V$. You do not real y need $K$ compact. It is enough that its closure is contained in the interior of $V$.

Comment: Thanks, I imagine that such $V$ necessarily exists?

Comment: Yes. Cover $K$ with open balls whose closure is contained in $V$ and take a finite subcover.